# I have a system I would like to implement, advise or theory would be pretty cool

Tags: database, ajax, html, user-interface, user-experience

So I want to extract the content from a system that is prebuilt...
it uses PHP + MySQL to CRUD the data, I am thinking of displaying the data in moveable + draggable windows that the logged in users can set, and be recalled upon logon. I am thinking cookies and AJAX with some HTML5 + CSS3 goodness, or even some Cappucino with mongoDB. PLease LMK what you all think. 
V/R 
CAM

Comment: Don't bother with Canvas for this, divs are your friend.  Just stick with something simple.  If you have lots of users, make sure your queries are clean.

Answer (score 6):

[It doesn't matter](http://creatingcode.com/2010/10/which-programming-language-should-i-use-to-build-my-application/).  Seriously, pick something that (1) interests you, (2) you've always wanted to learn, or (3) has the most jobs available in your area.

Once you are finished, add it to your portfolio and show it off.  If you like the languages you used, then use them again.  If not, then do something different next time.

Everyone is going to care about **how awesome your app is** not what language or technology you used in the process.